# how to compare first 3 and last 3 values in a 10 elements array?

Tags: javascript, logic, operators, logical-operators

i have 10 elements in an array, I want to compare first 3 and last 3 elements in the array if the elements are same or not.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a free code writing service, please show your code/effort and what the actual problem is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,3,2,1];

if(compare(arr)){
    alert('equal')
} else {
    alert('not equal')
}

function compare(arr){
  for(i = 0, j = 9; i < 3 ;i++, j--){
    if(arr[i] != arr[j]){ 
        return false;
    }
  }

  return true;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/369pdo4b/